# how to get utc fotmat date and time WCF from sql server by using Linq or something

Tags: linq-to-entities, wcf-ria-services

i am using DateTime.UtcNow to store the date in my database ..

while retrieving i need to filter on only today's date means for the latest ..

i need some suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have tons of records return from your query then you should filter out the date on sql server instead of using linq.  If you only have a couple hundreds of records, then use linq.